# Raspberry Pi for temperature measurement

Tags: pi-2

I want to start by saying that I’ve never built a raspberry pi, but after doing some reasearch I believe these tiny computers are a good base for my project. However, if anyone has other ideas, I’d be happy to hear them.

The project: I want a multi-probe temperature sensor that logs the temps and delivers them back to a user’s smart phone. I would want to connect to a home WiFi network.

After doing some research, I know I can add k type amplifiers to a pi. What I am not clear on is what model of a pi I would need. With 3 or 4 sensors, what other parts do I need? Are there enclosures available that I can buy to neatly package all of this (including the 3 or 4 k type receptacles), or would I just start with a generic project box? Would the box need a fan for cooling?

On the software side, I am a sql guy. I know some programming, but I feel like I need some direction. I want users to be able to set alert points and be able to review time over temperature stats.

Thank you for reading and response.

Jason

Comment: What are these k type receptacles? Googling shows there are power plugs used in Greenland by that name, but I doubt that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you meant a Type K thermocouple which can measure over a range  -270 C to +1260 C. There are ICs (MAX31855K) that will provide the interface between the sensor and the Raspberry Pi. For example code see:

https://learn.adafruit.com/thermocouple/python-circuitpython

You can either setup a webserver locally or maybe a cloud IOT with the MQTT protocol. For example,

https://learn.adafruit.com/mqtt-adafruit-io-and-you/overview

Comment: I've recently completed a similar project to the OP using this method. I used 4 MAX31855K's on an SPI bus, with the readings being taken by a python script, input into a mySQL database, and then displayed using PHP and Google charts. This is the output I get in the end. https://pasteboard.co/HM2RZhX.png

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend using it DS18B20 temperature sensors.

   - you can make a website where you will show the temperature
   - you can use some SW for monitoring like PRTG Network monitor
   - maybe u try Raspberry Pi Cayenne